# Server Error (500) when adding a blog post to django background

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

When I deployed django, I used nginx and uwsgi, and now I can log in to the homepage, but when I add an article from django-admin (ip:80/admin), I can't enter the edit page, and I see the server. Error (500), I don't know why, I will open the details of my article and I will not be able to modify the page. Please help me find out, what is the reason, thank you very much.
this is my models.py:

```
class HuoDong(models.Model):
    hdname = models.CharField('hdname',max_length = 200,null = False)
    hddescription = models.CharField('hddescription',max_length = 200,null = False, default = '活动描述')
    hdpicture = models.ImageField('picture',upload_to='static/images/',default = 'normal.jpg')
    hdblog = UEditorField(width=1000, height=1500, toolbars="full", imagePath="static/images/%%Y/%%m/", filePath="files/",upload_settings={"imageMaxSize":1204000},settings={},verbose_name='hdblog')
    hdtime = models.DateTimeField('time',auto_now_add = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hdname
```

And, I asked, after django deployment, I set DEBUG = False, this time I should go where to find the error message, I read uwsgi.log and nginx error.log, and did not find useful information

uwsgi.log:

```
[pid: 2282|app: 0|req: 123/474] 47.104.105.24 () {36 vars in 434 bytes} [Tue Mar 19 21:11:17 2019] GET / => generated 32201 bytes in 8 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 5 headers in 293 bytes (1 switches on core 1)
[pid: 2282|app: 0|req: 124/475] 139.162.88.63 () {32 vars in 421 bytes} [Tue Mar 19 21:15:08 2019] GET /echo.php?info=1234567890 => generated 77 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 3 headers in 100 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 2280|app: 0|req: 125/476] 180.156.58.29 () {44 vars in 936 bytes} [Tue Mar 19 21:15:21 2019] GET /admin/ssccapp/huodong/1/change/ => generated 27 bytes in 50 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 5 headers in 294 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 2280|app: 0|req: 126/477] 180.156.58.29 () {42 vars in 824 bytes} [Tue Mar 19 21:15:22 2019] GET /favicon.ico => generated 77 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 3 headers in 100 bytes (1 switches on core 1)
[pid: 2342|app: 0|req: 107/478] 194.50.254.170 () {32 vars in 473 bytes} [Tue Mar 19 21:24:03 2019] GET / => generated 32201 bytes in 9 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 5 headers in 293 bytes (1 switches on core 1)
[pid: 2281|app: 0|req: 125/479] 47.101.204.125 () {34 vars in 482 bytes} [Tue Mar 19 21:29:02 2019] GET / => generated 32201 bytes in 9 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 5 headers in 293 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 2281|app: 0|req: 126/480] 203.208.60.127 () {36 vars in 528 bytes} [Tue Mar 19 21:38:21 2019] GET /robots.txt => generated 77 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 3 headers in 100 bytes (1 switches on core 1)
[pid: 2342|app: 0|req: 108/481] 203.208.60.33 () {40 vars in 848 bytes} [Tue Mar 19 21:38:22 2019] GET / => generated 32201 bytes in 9 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 5 headers in 293 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 2282|app: 0|req: 125/482] 203.208.60.76 () {40 vars in 864 bytes} [Tue Mar 19 21:38:52 2019] GET /news/11/ => generated 18266 bytes in 8 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 3 headers in 111 bytes (1 switches on core 1)
[pid: 2282|app: 0|req: 126/483] 203.208.60.106 () {40 vars in 865 bytes} [Tue Mar 19 21:39:02 2019] GET /contact/ => generated 15621 bytes in 4 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 3 headers in 111 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 2280|app: 0|req: 127/484] 203.208.60.2 () {42 vars in 786 bytes} [Tue Mar 19 21:39:11 2019] GET /contact/js//static/js/easing.js => generated 77 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 3 headers in 100 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 2280|app: 0|req: 128/485] 203.208.60.20 () {40 vars in 864 bytes} [Tue Mar 19 21:39:52 2019] GET /picture/ => generated 14052 bytes in 4 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 3 headers in 111 bytes (1 switches on core 1)
[pid: 2342|app: 0|req: 109/486] 203.208.60.106 () {42 vars in 788 bytes} [Tue Mar 19 21:39:56 2019] GET /picture/js//static/js/easing.js => generated 77 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 3 headers in 100 bytes (1 switches on core 1)
[pid: 2281|app: 0|req: 127/487] 203.208.60.61 () {40 vars in 866 bytes} [Tue Mar 19 21:40:51 2019] GET /register/ => generated 13195 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 3 headers in 111 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 2281|app: 0|req: 128/488] 203.208.60.47 () {42 vars in 790 bytes} [Tue Mar 19 21:40:54 2019] GET /register/js//static/js/easing.js => generated 77 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 3 headers in 100 bytes (1 switches on core 1)
[pid: 2342|app: 0|req: 110/489] 203.208.60.35 () {38 vars in 585 bytes} [Tue Mar 19 21:55:36 2019] GET / => generated 32201 bytes in 10 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 5 headers in 293 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 2282|app: 0|req: 127/490] 216.245.197.254 () {26 vars in 305 bytes} [Tue Mar 19 21:57:24 2019] HEAD /robots.txt => generated 77 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.0 404) 3 headers in 100 bytes (1 switches on core 1)
```

nginx:error.log:

```
2019/03/19 19:20:04 [error] 2324#2324: *813 open() "/var/www/sscc2019/static/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 180.156.58.29, server: ssccracing.com, request: "GET /static/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "47.101.157.128", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1/"
2019/03/19 19:20:04 [error] 2324#2324: *812 open() "/var/www/sscc2019/static/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 180.156.58.29, server: ssccracing.com, request: "GET /static/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "47.101.157.128", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1/"
2019/03/19 19:20:04 [error] 2324#2324: *813 open() "/var/www/sscc2019/static/js/jquery.min.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 180.156.58.29, server: ssccracing.com, request: "GET /static/js/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "47.101.157.128", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1/"
2019/03/19 19:20:07 [error] 2324#2324: *815 open() "/var/www/sscc2019/static/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 180.156.58.29, server: ssccracing.com, request: "GET /static/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "47.101.157.128", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1/"
2019/03/19 19:20:07 [error] 2324#2324: *815 open() "/var/www/sscc2019/static/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 180.156.58.29, server: ssccracing.com, request: "GET /static/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "47.101.157.128", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1/"
2019/03/19 19:20:15 [error] 2324#2324: *815 open() "/var/www/sscc2019/static/js/jquery.min.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 180.156.58.29, server: ssccracing.com, request: "GET /static/js/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "47.101.157.128", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1/"
```

I checked some of my features and found that some connections are not available and an error will occur.
http://127.0.0.1/admin/ssccapp/huodong/add/
http://127.0.0.1/admin/ssccapp/huodong/1/change/

Comment: Those nginx errors is just because django seems not to server static files, which is something non-related here, are you using uwsgi? this looks like it died on uwsgi level because of uwsgi or python exception, can you check uwsgi logs?

Comment: thank you ,and I wrote the information in uwsgi.log on it, is this? I can only find this information for uwsgi.which one you said?

Comment: How are you running Django?

Comment: uwsgi:uwsgi --iniuwsgi.ini；nginx：service nginx start，the two commands I used,i can open my home page ,but i can not into the django-admin page to edit

Comment: You need to get python stacktraces out of uwsgi. I am suspecting you did not migrate database?

Comment: I migrated the database. I copied a copy of the database of the Ubuntu system and loaded it into the database of the server. The content of my homepage is imported from the database, but I can't drink it from the background admin page. , Server Error (500) will appear. Of course, not all can not be added, those information that is not too picture can be added, there are pictures in the article, this can not be added, and the information I uploaded from the front-end page can not be added from the background

Comment: you should log to file in your django app. have you set logging to file in settings.py? on development, the default is to only log to console, but on a deployed django app you'll want to change that to log to file.

Comment: how can i log to file? Do you mean setting STATIC_ROOT='/var/www/static/'and STATIC_URL='/static/' in settings.py,or setting 'local /static {}' in nginx